# Hashtable key with point

Tags: powershell, constructor, hashtable, object-initializers

How do I issue a hash table key with a point character, such as `FlatAppearance.BorderSize`, so that it is correct?

```
$Button = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{

    # This is not a valid entry
    FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
}
```

```
$Button = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{

    # This is not a valid entry too
    "FlatAppearance.BorderSize" = 0
}
```

```
$Button = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{

    # This is not a valid entry too too
    FlatAppearance = @{ BorderSize = 0 }
}
```

Of course, I can write it like that

```
$Button = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{}
$Button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
```

However, it is more convenient to write inside the hash table. But how? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [`Button`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.Button) type's `.FlatAppearance` property is of type [`FlatButtonAppearance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.FlatButtonAppearance), there's **no good solution in this case**, because the **`FlatButtonAppearance` type has *no public, parameterless* constructor**.

If it did, you would be able to write:

```bash
using namespace System.Windows.Forms

$Button = [Button] @{

    # !! This is how you would generally do it, but
    # !! IN THIS CASE IT DOESN'T WORK, due to lack of an appropriate constructor.
    FlatAppearance = [FlatButtonAppearance] @{ BorderSize = 0 }
}
```

The above syntax is akin to C#'s *object initializer* syntax, explained in the next section.

---

##### Object initializer syntax in PowerShell:

For a **cast to a type literal (`[...]`) from a hashtable (`@{ ... }`)** or **preexisting `[pscustomobject]` instance**<sup>[1]</sup> to perform **implicit construction** (implicit creation of an instance) and then **multi-property initialization** to work, the following **prerequisites** must be met:

- The target type must have a *constructor* (possibly among others<sup>[2]</sup>) that is:

  - public
  - *and* takes *no parameters*<sup>[3]</sup>
- The names of the type's *public properties* must match the hashtable entries' keys and the entries' values must be have the same or a compatible type as the target properties.

This allows PowerShell to create an instance behind the scenes simply by calling `new SomeType()` (`[SomeType]::new()` in PowerShell syntax), followed by assigning the public properties' values from the hashtable entries of the same name.

Note: Such casts, available in PowerShell v3+, are in effect *syntactic sugar* for calling the
[`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) cmdlet with the `-Property` parameter; only the latter works in v2.

---

Aside from consulting a type's documentation, you can easily **inspect a type's constructors in PowerShell** by calling the PowerShell-supplied static `::new` method *without parentheses* (`()`):

```bash
PS> [System.Windows.Forms.FlatButtonAppearance]::new
# NO OUTPUT, which means the type has no public constructors at all.

# [ProcessStartInfo] has several public constructors, among them
# a public parameterless one, so you *can* initialize it by hashtable.
PS> [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]::new

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo new()
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo new(string fileName)
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo new(string fileName, string arguments)
```

To **determine a type's public, writeable instance properties**:

```bash
PS> [System.Windows.Forms.FlatButtonAppearance].GetProperties('Public, Instance') | 
       ? CanWrite | Select-Object Name, PropertyType

Name               PropertyType        
----               ------------        
BorderSize         System.Int32        
BorderColor        System.Drawing.Color
CheckedBackColor   System.Drawing.Color
MouseDownBackColor System.Drawing.Color
MouseOverBackColor System.Drawing.Color
```

---

<sup>[1] For instance, this is useful for objects deserialized from JSON, which become `[pscustomobject]` instances; e.g.: `$obj = '{ "Text": "Submit" }' | ConvertFrom-Json; $button = [Button] $obj`</sup>

<sup>[2] Edge case: There mustn't also be a *single*-parameter public constructor with one of the following parameter types, because it would bind the cast operand as-is:</sup>

- `[object]` *or*
- when casting from a hashtable (`@{ ... }`): `[hashtable]` or `[System.Collections.IDictionary]`
- when casting from a `[pscustomobject]` instance: `[psobject]` or `[pscustomobject]`

<sup>[3] Conveniently, if you define a type (class) without declaring *any* constructor, you get a public parameterless one *by default*; e.g., in the following PowerShell example class `Foo` *implicitly* provides such a constructor:

`class Foo { [string] $Bar }; $foo = [Foo] @{ Bar = 'None' }`</sup>