# PowerShell - Why is my script creating an object with the default class fields?

Tags: powershell

In my script I am attempting to create PowerShell objects from a text file. Here is a sample of a text file.

```
junk data at the 

beginning of

the file


Item: Car
In Stock: YES
Make: Ford
Model: Taurus
Color: Blue
Miles: 0
Item: Car
Miles: 0
Item: Truck
Item: SUV
Item: Car
In Stock: YES
Make: Honda
Model: Civic
Color: Red
Miles: 0

junk
data at the 

end
```

Sometimes these files are generated with junk data at the beginning and end. I try to account for this with my Select-String statement.

Here is my script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]$File
)

class Item {
    [string] $Item = ''
    [string] $Found = 'NO'
    [string] ${In Stock}  = 'N/A'
    [string] $Make = 'N/A'
    [string] $Model = 'N/A'
    [string] $Color = 'N/A'
    [string] $Miles = 'N/A'
  }


[string[]]$Keep = @("Item:", "In Stock:", "Make:", "Model:", "Color:", "Miles:")
  
(Get-Content $File | Select-String -Pattern ($Keep -join "|") |
    Out-String) -split '(?m)(?=^Item:)' -ne '' -replace '(?m)^(.+?):', '$1=' |
        ConvertFrom-StringData | ForEach-Object {
            $Obj = [Item] $_
            if ($Obj.'In Stock' -eq 'Yes') {
                $Obj.Found = 'YES'
            }
            Write-Output $Obj 
        }
```

The script works a lot better than it did. Many thanks to another user that helped me get this far.

When I run the script, I get an EXTRA object at the top with all the default values defined in the class. Why is that?

Here is the output:

```
Item:
Found: NO
In Stock: N/A
Make: N/A
Model: N/A
Color: N/A
Miles: N/A

Item: Car
Found: YES
In Stock: YES
Make: Ford
Model: Taurus
Color: Blue
Miles: 0

Item: Car
Found: NO
In Stock: N/A
Make: N/A
Model: N/A
Color: N/A
Miles: 0

Item: Truck
Found: NO
In Stock: N/A
Make: N/A
Model: N/A
Color: N/A
Miles: N/A

Item: SUV
Found: NO
In Stock: N/A
Make: N/A
Model: N/A
Color: N/A
Miles: N/A

Item: Car
Found: YES
In Stock: YES
Make: Honda
Model: Civic
Color: Red
Miles: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to your `ForEach-Object` call in which the `[Item]` cast happens (see explanation below) starts with an *empty* line, which results in an extra output object (with all the class' default values), because it is in effect like `[Item] @{}` (because something like `` "`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData `` outputs an *empty* hashtable), which in turn is like simply calling the (parameterless default) constructor, `[Item]::new()`.

You can avoids this empty line as follows (note the use of `.Line` and avoiding a `Get-Content` call in favor of passing the file path directly to `Select-String`):

```sh
(
  (Select-String -Pattern ($Keep -join "|") -LiteralPath $File).Line | Out-String
) -split '(?m)(?=^Item:)' -ne '' -replace '(?m)^(.+?):', '$1=' |
  ConvertFrom-StringData | ForEach-Object {
    $Obj = [Item] $_
    if ($Obj.'In Stock' -eq 'Yes') {
      $Obj.Found = 'YES'
    }
    Write-Output $Obj
  }
```

The reason for the empty line (which appears both at the start and and at the end) is that you're directly sending [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s output objects to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string), which results in the same *for-display* string formatting that you would see in the console. Accessing the `.Line` property on `Select-String`'s output objects avoids that, as it outputs just *strings* (rather than the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances emitted by default), which adds no formatting.

On a side note: `Out-String` unexpectedly always appends a trailing newline to its output string; this problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).

---

**Explanation of the `[Item]` casting technique:**

On instantiation of class `[Item]`, the properties have the default values as specified in the class definition, unless you override them later.

By casting a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) - as output by [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) - to `[Item]`, those of its entries whose keys match the names of properties of the class implicitly set those properties; all others keep their defaults (and no entries with keys that do *not* match property names are allowed).

This construction by casting from a hashtable is explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60239793/45375).

---

A simplified example with a hashtable *literal* `@{ ... }`:

```sh
class Item {
  $A = 'A_default'
  $B = 'B_default'
  $C = 'C_default'
}

# Construct an [Item] instance and assign to its .B property
[Item] @{ B = 'B_NEW' }
```

The above yields:

```
A         B     C
-         -     -
A_default B_NEW C_default
```

Comment: @AbrahamZinala A sample text file is posted above. The actual files have possible sensitive info at the top and bottom. As I am looking into into this more, it seems my script is picking up on a blank line or something that is causing the loop to output an "extra" object. Which is strange because I thought that I am grabbing only the lines I need with the Select-String statement.