# Object instantiation with predefined properties

Tags: powershell, syntax, object-initializers

I am studying the mailkit library, I found just such a construction in one line in c#

```
msg.Body = new TextPart("html") { Text = "<b>html content</b>" };
```

on Powershell I can do as many as three lines

```
$TextPart = [MimeKit.TextPart]::new("html")
$TextPart.Text = "<b>html content</b>"
$msg.Body = $TextPart
```

Is it possible in powershell to also write this on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to also simplify this in PowerShell

```
$msg.Body = New-Object MimeKit.TextPart -ArgumentList 'html' -Property @{Text = '<b>html content</b>' }
```

The -Property parameter of New-Object will accept a hashtable of property names:property values where you can specify as many properties as you like.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Daniel's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68403822/45375) with a more convenient **PSv3+ alternative**, where you can *cast* a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) `@{ ... }` or custom object (`[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`) to the target type:

```sh
[MimeKit.TextPart] @{ Text = '<b>html content</b>' }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60239793/45375) for a comprehensive discussion of the prerequisites for and constraints on this technique (equally applies to use of [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object)).