# How can I define PitPolicy <PITPolicyRule[]> from AWS.Tools.Drs in powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, types

I am not sure if I am missing something obvious but I am trying to use
New-EDRSReplicationConfigurationTemplate
[text](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-EDRSReplicationConfigurationTemplate.html)

from the AWS.Tools.Drs package [text](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWS.Tools.Drs/4.1.332).

I cannot see how to define -PitPolicy <PITPolicyRule[]>. It looks like it takes a bool, a few integers and a constant [text](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Drs/TPITPolicyRule.html).

I have tried numerous ways of passing the information for example;

```
[PSCustomObject[]] $pitPol = @("interval=4", "retentionDuration=168", "units=HOUR")
```

but always end up with messages of the nature cannot convert what I am passing to the type: Amazon.Drs.Model.PITPolicyRule

[image]

given values for interval=4, retentionDuration=168, units="HOUR" how am I supposed to construct <PITPolicyRule[]?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot verify this solution, but the information in your question suggests that the following *may* work:

```
$pitPol = [Amazon.Drs.Model.PITPolicyRule] @{
  interval = 4
  retentionDuration = 168
  units = 'HOUR'
}
```

This assumes that the [`[PITPolicyRule]`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/drs/latest/APIReference/API_PITPolicyRule.html) class has a (public) parameter-less constructor, which does appear to be the case, based on [your alternative documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Drs/TPITPolicyRule.html)).

The above causes PowerShell to construct a `[PITPolicyRule]` instance behind the scenes and make it set its properties based on the entries matching the property names in the [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) `@{ ... }`) being used in the cast; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60239793/45375) for more information about this object-initialization technique.

Note that even though the `-PitPolicy` is declared to accept an *array* of `PitPolicyRule` values, PowerShell's parameter binder allows you to pass a *single instance* of the declared type as well.